# bigquery aggregate all rows that have at least one common element of the corresponding array

Tags: arrays, group-by, google-bigquery

In big query, I have this table:

```
orders      invoices
2100        \[1,3\]
1200        \[3\]
3300        \[2\]
1100        \[1\]
4400        \[4\]
3100        \[2\]
```

Where orders are numbers and invoices are arrays of numbers.

This is what I would like:

```
orders      invoices             group 
2100        \[1,3\]              A 
1200        \[3\]                A 
3300        \[2\]                B 
1100        \[1\]                A
4400        \[4\]                C 
3100        \[2\]                B
```

In the example, order 1200 and 1100 don't have an invoice in common, but they both are connected to order 2100 so all of the 3 goes together.

I would like to create a new column (or substitute the invoices column) for each order so that all the orders that have in common at least one invoice will be in the same group. Moreover, if an order can be associated with multiple others by different invoices, all will be in the same group.

We don't know how many orders can be connected to an invoice, how many invoices to orders and so how big can be a group of orders.

I hope I explained the problem well.
Thank you for the help